# Rosdep failed to detect successful installation of [boost --with-python] on MacOS 10.9.5

Tags: ros, python, boost, macosx, homebrew

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My environment:
Mac OS maverick, 10.9.5; Xcode 6.0.1

I basically followed the instruction here: 
http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source

Error:

> $rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y 
> executing command [brew install boost --with-python]
> Warning: boost-1.56.0 already installed
> ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
> homebrew: Failed to detect successful installation of [boost --with-python]

I have both boost and boost-python installed by homebrew:

> $brew list
> autoconf        eigen           icon-naming-utils   libyaml         pyqt            urdfdom
> automake        flann           ilmbase         log4cxx         qhull           urdfdom_headers
> **boost**           fltk            imagemagick     opencv          qt          vtk5
> **boost-python**        freetype        intltool        openexr         sbcl            wget
> cmake           gettext         jpeg            openssl         sip         yaml-cpp-0.3
> collada-dom     glew            libpng          pcl         szip
> console_bridge      gtest           libtiff         pcre            tango-icon-theme
> cppunit         hdf5            libtool         pkg-config      tinyxml

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194157/rosdep-failed-to-detect-successful-installation-of-%5Bboost---with-python%5D--on-macos-10.9.5/) by [nikai](https://answers.ros.org/users/20384/nikai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem. Asked here. Got solution... kind of hahaha https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/339#issuecomment-57802675 . Now I'm stuck at http://answers.ros.org/question/194158/bondcpp-fails/. Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [Tiberius](https://answers.ros.org/users/20385/tiberius/) with karma: 36 on 2014-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nikai](https://answers.ros.org/users/20384/nikai/) on 2014-10-03**:
Thanks Tiberius! So basically I just ignore the complaints by rosdep and continue the catkin compilation?

**Comment by [nikai](https://answers.ros.org/users/20384/nikai/) on 2014-10-03**:
Actually I have the new errors:

CMake Error at cmake/empy.cmake:29 (message):
Unable to find either executable 'empy' or Python module 'em'...  try
installing the package 'python-empy'

How did you resolve this?

**Comment by [Tiberius](https://answers.ros.org/users/20385/tiberius/) on 2014-10-03**:
Yeah! I got that one too! I just installed it. I did like http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source says. There is a section about it.